# Rendering stenciljs stateless components

Tags: stenciljs

I've been using StencilJS for some time now,
and coming from React background, my immediate instinct for writing some components is to write them stateless.
However, the stencil documentation doesn't mention the stateless components at all.
That's why I am writing here to learn other people experience with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write functional components inside Stencil elements. [As an example](https://github.com/mattdsteele/web-bluetooth-bike-leds/blob/master/src/components/my-app/my-app.tsx):

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-app',
  styleUrl: 'my-app.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyApp {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loading />
       </div>
    );
  }
}

const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div class="loading">
      <h1>Activating Santa</h1>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this case `<Loading>` is a stateless functional component similar to React's model - you can obtain its props and get children, etc.

Stateless Stencil components can not be exported as top-level Web Components - those must be defined as classes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Have you figured out the way to use css modules with stateless components?
I've managed to run it with JS objects, but I would like to use scss with it

Answer (score 2):

You should look at functional components: https://stenciljs.com/docs/functional-components to create stateless components, and they:

- aren't compiled into web components,
- don't create a DOM node,
- don't have a Shadow DOM or scoped styles,
- don't have lifecycle hooks,

According to the doc, if a component has to hold state, deal with events, etc, it should probably be a class component. If a component's purpose is to simply encapsulate some markup so it can be reused across your app, it can probably be a functional component